# Processing multiple concurrent read queries in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, postgresql-10

I am planning to use AWS RDS Postgres version 10.4 and above for storing data in a single table comprising of ~15 columns.

My use case is to serve:
1. Periodically (after 1 hour) store/update rows in to this table.
2. Periodically (after 1 hour) fetch data from the table say 500 rows at a time.
3. Frequently fetch small data (10 rows) from the table (100's of queries in parallel)

Does AWS RDS Postgres support serving all of above use cases

I am aware of Read-Replicas support, but is there any in built load balancer to serve the queries that come in parallel?

How many read queries can Postgres be able to process concurrently?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usecases seems to be a normal fit for all relational database systems. So I would say: yes.

The question is: how fast the DB can handle the 100 queries (3).

In general the postgresql documentation is one of the best I ever read. So give it a try:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/parallel-query.html

But also take into consideration how big your data is!

That said, try w/o read replicas first! You might not need them.

Comment: Can you also please let know what is the default size (minimum size) of PostgreSql Text data type, maximum I know is 1GB

Comment: You can read everything in the official documentation. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-character.html

Comment: I went through the link, but still could not find postgresql default (minimum) text storage size.

Comment: Can you tell me the reason, why you need that? Do you want to calculate the DB size?

Comment: I want to know minimum storage overhead when column type is text vs any other column type.